# nokogiri scrape all children divs from a selected div

Tags: html, css, ruby, web, nokogiri

I was playing around with Nokogiri in my free time, and I am afraid I got really stuck.I am trying to solve this problem since this morning (almost 8h now :( ) and it looks that I didn't progress at all. On the [website](https://boards.4chan.org/g/catalog) I want to scrape all the threads on the page.So far I realize that parent for all threads is

```
<div id="threads" class="extended-small">
```

each thread consist of 3 elements:

1. link to the image
2. div#title that contains value of replies(R) and images(I)
3. div#teaser that contains the name of the thread

My question is how can I select the children of the id='threads'
and push each child with 3 elements to the array ?
As you can see in this code I don't really know what I am doing and I would very , very much appreciate

```
require 'httparty'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'json'
require 'pry'
require 'csv'

page = HTTParty.get('https://boards.4chan.org/g/catalog')

parse_page = Nokogiri::HTML(page)

threads_array = []

threads = parse_page.search('.//*[@id="threads"]/div') do |a|
    post_id = a.text
    post_pic = a.text
    post_title = a.text
    post_teaser = a.text
threads_array.push(post_id,post_pic,post_title,post_teaser)
end

CSV.open('sample.csv','w') do |csv|
    csv << threads_array
end

Pry.start(binding)
```

[image: page and code]

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need the minimum HTML in the question, not as an image.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't look like the raw HTML source contains those fields which is why you're not seeing it when parsing with HTTParty and Nokogiri. It looks like they put the data in a JS variable farther up. Try this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

page = HTTParty.get('https://boards.4chan.org/g/catalog')
m = page.match(/var catalog = ({.*?});var/)
json_str = m.captures.first
catalog = JSON.parse(json_str)
pp catalog
```

Whether that is robust enough I'll let you decide :)

Comment: You can use shorthand notation `page[/var catalog = ({.*?});var/, 1]` for first match group of a regexp